# PAM Locked out of all accounts

Tags: debian, authentication, pam

I went to this site: https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/PAM and I pasted the given code into the said files - common-account, common-auth, -common-password, common-session.

For example, I pasted this:

```
account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so
account     required      pam_permit.so
```

into my common-account file..

Now I cannot access any of my 6 Debian user accounts! Err...

Is there any way to log in and change this code, or do I need to reinstall!

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use single mode, add `single` to the Linux command line at the bootloader.

http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-recover-root-password-under-linux-with-single-user-mode/

or run a live CD/USB system, mount root file system and revert your changes.